# Chrome extension and angular2 prepare for production

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, angular, typescript, gulp

I have a simple chrome extension with popup and when you click on browser action the popup shows up and loads angular2 application.
Angular2 applicaiton is simple:

main.ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component'

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    declarations: [//all components
        AppComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [//main component
        AppComponent
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>`
})
export class AppComponent { name = 'Angular'; }
```

in index.html I add script

```
System.import('app/main.js').catch(function(err) {
     console.error(err);
});
```

and when I run the extension it works fine, but now I need to concatenate all the .ts files to one javascript file. Usually I do this with gulp, but after concatenation my extension does not work... Can someone please explain me how to to prepare .ts files for deployment??

**UPDATE 1**

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "One-click Kittens",
  "description": "This extension demonstrates a browser action with kittens.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [
    "https://secure.flickr.com/"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "img/icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
    "js": [
      "lib/jquery.min.js"
    ],
    "matches": [
      "http://*/*",
      "https://*/*"
    ],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self",
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "lib/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: You're going to have problems with the required file structure of a Chrome Extension, as defined in the manifest. Can you show the manifest too?

Comment: Quite a good guide here: https://www.sitepoint.com/chrome-extension-angular-2/

Comment: @Tom updated question with manifest.json

Comment: See full documentation here for angular2 and chrome extension here https://medium.com/@PardeepJain/build-your-own-chrome-extension-using-angular-4-ecedbd7404cc